# "invalid sender" when sending a signed transaction on bsc on PHP

Tags: evm, bsc, web3-providers, php

I'm trying to replicate a script that I have already running in nodejs in php.

On PHP I'm using "web3p/web3.php": "dev-master", "web3p/ethereum-tx": "^0.4.3" libraries.

When I send the signed transaction I'm always getting a "invalid sender" response.
The transaction data is generated using 1inch.exchange API which works perfectly on nodejs.

I'm on PHP7.4 with GMP installed.

Here's a **short version** of my script

```
use Web3\Providers\HttpProvider;
use Web3\RequestManagers\HttpRequestManager;
use Web3p\EthereumTx\Transaction;

$web3 = new Web3(new HttpProvider(new HttpRequestManager($_ENV['API_MORALIS_BSC_URL'], 10)));
$eth = $web3->eth;

$params = [
        "fromAddress" => $_ENV['ADDRESS_1'],
        "fromTokenAddress" => $_ENV['COIN_1'],
        "toTokenAddress" => $_ENV['COIN_2'],
        "slippage" => 1,
        "amount" => "10000000000000000",
    ];

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['http_errors' => false, 'timeout' => 10]);
$response = $client->get($_ENV['API_1INCH_BSC_URL']."swap", [ "query" => $params ]);

$transactionParams = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(),true)['tx'];

// TRANSACTION PARAMS
// Array
// (
//     [from] => 0x3f9E320Fc------0DBA74d43c539a63bf
//     [to] => 0x11111112------e05771c2dccff4faa26
//     [data] => 0x7c025200000000000000000000000000baf90------0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000cfee7c08
//     [value] => 0
//     [gas] => 198325
//     [gasPrice] => 15000000000
//     [nonce] => 1d4
//     [chainId] => 38
// )

$transaction = new Transaction($transactionParams);

$signedTransaction = '0x'.$transaction->sign($_ENV['PRIVATE_KEY_1']);

$eth->sendRawTransaction($signedTransaction, function ($err, $tx) { $err->getMessage(); });
```

I'd tried with and without including *nonce*, *from* and *chainid* on the transaction params.

I'm using a *Moralis* node, but the same happens with an *Ankr* node. Both nodes work fine when I run the nodejs version of the script.

I've been struggling whit this for a few days now, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this [issue on github](https://github.com/web3p/web3.php/issues/84).
Check you chainId format.
With bsc testnet i found this:

```
'chainId' => 97 //works
'chainId' => 0x61 //works
'chainId' => '97' //works
'chainId' => '0x61' //invalid sender
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Try all possible combinations and none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with web3p. Ended making my own approach based on kornrunner tx signer:

https://github.com/drlecks/Simple-Web3-Php

I made a working "send eth" example (Example/example.send.php) tested on ethereum (mainnet), ropsten (etherum testnet) and mumbai (polygon testnet).